# Cognitive services. Azure endpoint not working

Tags: c#, azure, unity-game-engine, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I integrated the 30 days free trial of the Speech to Text of Microsoft Cognitive Services.

```
var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("fake", "westus");

   using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config))
      {
        lock (threadLocker)
        {
            waitingForReco = true;
        }

        var result = recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync().Result;

        string newMessage = string.Empty;
        if (result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
        {

            newMessage = result.Text;
        }
        else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.NoMatch)
        {
            newMessage = "NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.";
        }
        else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
        {
            var cancellation = CancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
            newMessage = $"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason} ErrorDetails={cancellation.ErrorDetails}";
        }

        lock (threadLocker)
        {
            message = newMessage;
            waitingForReco = false;
        }
    }
```

When i connect to the api with the free demo key it works. When i create an Azure Cognitive Service in Azure it always returns Canceled.

Are there any other differences i have to configure for this demo key and a production key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might created the wrong service. For cognitive services, there are many types, such as face, luis, speechservice and so on. In this case, you need to create a speech service by searching speech when you create a resource on azure portal.

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps!